# Crenellated or Castellated

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

I read an article today. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-60767454 It used the word "crenellated". I thought I knew the word "castellated", but I'm getting more confused.

The best explanation I can muster with Google search, with minimal effort I must admit, is the follows. https://wikidiff.com/crenellated/castellated

**Crenellated**

*Adjective*
Having turrets or battlements, like a castle.

- 2004 , , Picador, paperback edition, page 2
  Finally he walked slowly into a vast Italian space, with towers and castellated roofs, and a sky the colour of dark blue ink, smooth and consistent.
  (obsolete) Enclosed within a building.
  a fountain or cistern castellated
  (Johnson)

*Derived terms*

- castellated nut

*Related terms*

- castle * castellation

**Castellated**

*Alternative forms*

- crenelated

*Verb*
(crenellate)

*Adjective*
(en adjective)
Having crenellations or battlements
Having a series of square indentations

*Quotations*

- 2001 — , Artemis Fowl , p 52 *: She could see the town below her, nestled on top of a low hill, surrounded by a crenellated wall from the Middle Ages.

I am still confused. Would you please help me to understand the similarities and the differences among "crenellated" and "castellated"? Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps there was a fine distinction between them in a world where such things were important, in the same way that the inhabitants of the frozen north have many words for the different types of snow and ice. Why does there have to be only one word?

Comment: If I had to decide, it would be that 'castellated' means a house that is fortified by various means, whereas 'crenellations' are specifically the toothed parapet around the edge of the walls.

Comment: Thanks. I took the courage to pick up my copy of Collins CoBuild. **crenellated** A crenellated wall has gaps in the top openings through which to fire at attackers; a technical term in architecture. ... *crenellated turrents.* **castellated** A castellated wall or building has turrets and battlements like a castle; a technical term in architecture. ... *a castellated hotel styled from local honey-coloured sandstone.*

Answer (score 6):

These words differ. To crenellate has a broader meaning:

OED

> **crenellate | crenelate**, v.
>
> *transitive.* **To furnish with battlements**, to embattle *; **to furnish with embrasures or loopholes.**
>
> 1851   T. H. Turner Some Acct. Domest. Archit. I. 157 (note)    *Laurence de Ludlow had licence to crenellate his mansion of Stoke-Say.*
>
> 1875   C. Clery Minor Tactics xvii. 252   *Walls that have been loopholed or crenelated, afford material aid.*

From crena - [notch or incision](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crena#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20crena,notch%2C%20indentation%2C%20cleft%2C%20scallop) - c.f. crenellated leaves

> **castellate,** v.
>
> **1.** *transitive*. **To build in the manner of a castle; to build with battlements.**
>
> 1840   H. Taylor Autobiogr. (1885) I. xx. 321   *The citizen who castellates a Villa at Richmond.*

*in this sense = arranged in preparation for a battle.

Comment: I was hoping the distinction was to be found in the building codes and Royal Permit system of King Henry VIII. But it appears that the neither word was in use much before 1800. You had to procure a Royal dispensation to build a real castle with real battlements, but you could build a gewgaw castle without one.

Comment: Then there are merlons.